# tips for moving logic out of componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux connected component and I am using `componentDidUpdate` for a lot of logic and it is starting to get messy.

My `componentDidUpdate` looks a bit like this:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
    if (this.props === prevProps) {
      return;
    }

    const {
      history,
      a,
      b,
      c
    } = this.props;

    if (!prevProps.a && !a) {
      this.proceedToNextStep();
      return;
    }

    if (b.length === b.length + 1) {
      history.push(rootUrl);
      return;
    }

    if (c != prevProps.c) {
      // do stuff
      return;
    }
  }
```

The props will change due to redux actions but I don't know a better place to determine where something has changed in the redux connected component.

This was perhaps wrong for one property but more logic is appearing in here and this is already messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your logic in:

- [`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops): this will at least avoid the componenent re-rendering before execute your component logic. The newProps will contains the props injected by Redux `connect`
- [`mapsTateToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options): the Redux `connect` third parameter is a callback that is sent the merged props: (state props + dispatch props + own component props)
- [observables](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md) wrapped in [Redux promise](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk): This is for me the best option to handle logic because it doesn't involve React Components: I can chain js logic (with observables) and, at each step of the logic execution, I can trigger `dispatch()` and access the application Redux `state`. [`redux-observable`](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/docs/basics/Epics.md) module mixes both [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md) module (observables) and [Redux promise](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) module (redux promise) for easier uses.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) is not suggested anymore. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops